# Reading line count with strtok in c

Tags: c

For my program I must give the word and line count of a file. I know their is an easier way to do it using if statements but I am required to use strtock.
It currently gives me a correct word count but my line count is consistently wrong.

Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int wordcount(char *string);
int linecount(char *string);

int main(){
    char * buffer=0;
    long length;
    char filename[50];

    printf("Enter file name: \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    FILE *f= fopen(filename, "rb");

    if(f){
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
        length=ftell(f);
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
        buffer=malloc(length);
        if (buffer){
            fread(buffer,1,length,f);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    if(buffer){
        printf("wordcount: %i\n", wordcount(buffer));
        printf("linecount: %i\n", linecount(buffer));
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


int wordcount(char *string){
    int count=0;
    for(string=strtok(string," =.!,;\n");string; string=strtok(NULL, " -.!,;\n"))
        count++;
    return count;
}

int linecount(char *string){
    int count=1;
    for(string=strtok(string,"\n");string; string=strtok(NULL, "\n"))
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

I know I am missing something inside my strtok that isn't counting but I am not sure what it is. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `buffer` from `fread(buffer,1,length,f);` was `"abc\nXYZ"` , would you count that as 1 line or 2?

Comment: `buffer=malloc(length);` should be `buffer=malloc(length+1); buffer[length]=0;` to use later as a  _string_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` destroys the string, it writes null terminators.

If you want to use `strtok`, you have to make a copy of the string, and use `strtok` on the copy.

For example:

```c
int wordcount(const char *string) {
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(copy, string);
    int count = 0;
    for (copy = strtok(copy, " =.!,;\n"); copy; copy = strtok(NULL, " -.!,;\n"))
        count++;
    free(copy);
    return count;
}

int linecount(const char *string) {
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(copy, string);
    int count = 0;
    for (copy = strtok(copy, "\n"); copy; copy = strtok(NULL, "\n"))
        count++;
    free(copy);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Since you know the length of the buffer in `main()`, you could pass the length to the functions too.  The original code doesn’t allocate enough space for a null byte at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use strtok twice on the same string like that, strtok splits the string to several strings.
I recommend running strtok only on copies, preferably local ones.
Something like that:

```
int wordcount(char *input){
  char string[strlen(input) + 1];
  int count=0;
  strcpy(string, input);
  for(string=strtok(string," =.!,;\n");string; string=strtok(NULL, " -.!,;\n"))
    count++;
  return count;
}

int linecount(char * input){
  char string[strlen(input) + 1];
  int count=0;
  strcpy(string, input);
  for(string=strtok(string,"\n");string; string=strtok(NULL, "\n"))
    count++;
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I'd expect a compiler error with `char string[strlen(input) + 1]; ... string=strtok(string," =.!,;\n");`